# If I use mod_deflate, will stripping whitespace in my outputted HTML files also help increase speed?

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, mod-deflate

I am already using HTACCESS through Apache to GZIP the contents of all HTML, CSS and JS files that are served.

I use a program called Koala that automatically minifies JS and CSS output to have zero whitespace, but since I am using PHP to dynamically generated the HTML code, there is no clear way to eliminate unnecessary whitespace in the HTML file that ultimately gets served to the browser.

Since I am already GZIPping the contents of the file, is this even necessary at all?

Comment: How big are you HTML files? Gzip will take care of html white space for you in it's compression algorithm and realistically it shouldn't be THAT much of a difference. You may want to look into optimizing your server side code before trying to nit-pick on the white space.

Comment: The page I am currently writing has a vast amount of images (large slideshows), but aside from those tags, I have kept it as minimal as possible.  <img/> excluded, I would estimate probably no more than 150 lines if I were to cut out extra empty lines and HTML comment tags.

Comment: honestly I wouldn't even worry about it. Your images are going to take far longer to load that 150 lines of code. Even with whitespace it'd take a few ms